# AS3 Custom Event not firing on Document Class ( using DispatchEvent actionscript)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, dispatchevent

Im trying to get my head round what is needed to catch event "Beep2", using dispatchEvent. The function "DoNext" is not firing, even though Im able to produce a trace result of the dispatchEvent "Beep2 true".

This code uses a CustomEvent Class to Extend the Event Class. Its right on my limit of knowledge so far, so any help would be appreciated. :)

Thanks.

package
//Main.as (Document class)

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Main extends MovieClip 
{
    public var ftasks:MovieClip;
    public function Main () 
    {
        ftasks = new filetasks();
        addChild(ftasks);
        ftasks.addEventListener(CustomEvent.BEEP2, DoNext);
    }

//not firing
    public function DoNext (evt:Event) 
{
        trace("DoNext"); 
    }


}
```

package 
//CustomEvent.as

```
//Extend Event class.
import flash.events.Event;
public class CustomEvent extends Event
{
    public static const BEEP1 ="Beep1";
    public static const BEEP2 ="Beep2";

    //Declare Event Constructor
    public function CustomEvent(type:String, bubbles:Boolean)
    {
        super(type, bubbles);
        type = this.type;
        bubbles = this.bubbles;
        trace(type, bubbles);
    }

    public override function clone():Event
    {
        return new CustomEvent(type, bubbles);
    }
}
```

package 
//filetasks.as

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

public class filetasks extends MovieClip 
{
    public var Ref;

    public function filetasks (_Ref) 
    {
        Ref = _Ref;
        dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.BEEP2, true));
    }

    public function done (evt:MouseEvent) 
    {
        dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.BEEP1, true));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is, that the event is fired, before you even added the EventListener.

Comment: Yep your right, a quick removal of the dispatch event in the constructor for filetask function did the trick...